# How to dynamically apply an operator

Tags: ruby

I have a hash:

```
rule => {
  :quantity => 2,
  :operator => ">="
}
```

and

```
@quantity = 1
```

Using `@quantity`, `rule[:operator]`, and `rule[:quantity]`, I want to dynamically express:

```
if @quantity rule[:operator] rule[:quantity] # SyntaxError
```

such that it evaluates as:

```
if 1 >= 2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators in Ruby are "syntactic sugar" for methods.

```
a >= b
```

is equivalent to

```
a.>=(b)
```

Therefore, you can use [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) or [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) to dynamically call operators as methods.

```
op1 = '>='
op2 = '<'

1.send(op1, 2) # => false 
1.send(op2, 2) # => true
```

In your example, you'd use it like this:

```
if @quantity.send(rule[:operator], rule[:quantity])
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this would be to use the [`Method#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
@quantity.method(rule[:operator])[rule[:quantity]]
```